# Как оператором = вернуть значение

Tags: c++

Есть задание разработать класс Triangle и в нем перегрузить оператор =, который возвращал бы площадь этого треугольника. Вопрос в том, как это сделать? То есть как оператором = вернуть тип double, если это метод класса треугольник.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо перегрузить оператор приведения к типу `double`, к примеру вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle () {}

    operator double() const
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Triangle tr;
    double res = tr;
    std::cout << "Square:" << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но я бы не стал так делать, это очень не очевидное действие, на мой взгляд, лучше определить просто функцию `square` и пользоваться её.

```
#include <iostream>

class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle () {}

    double square() const
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Triangle tr;
    std::cout << "Square:" << tr.square() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `лучше определить просто функцию square`. От автора: `Есть задание разработать класс Triangle и в нем перегрузить оператор =`.

Comment: @raviga, возможно, Вы предложите лучшее решение проблемы. На мой взгляд, я сделал то что хотел автор, хоть и немного другим способом.